# By clicking on next jQuery method to load next and previous pages asynchronously

Tags: jquery, html

Below I have mentioned my HTM code. By clicking on "next-nav" it has to check the "active" id and move to next ID. Same as By clicking "priview-nav" it has move to previous ID

// HTML code

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <span class="priview-nav"></span>  // previous button
    <span class="next-nav"></span>  // next button
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="page-1"></div>  // active ID
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="page-3"></div>  // Next Id to load
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="page-4"></div>  
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="page-5"></div>  
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="page-18"></div>
```

Code from comments

```
$('.ss-help .next-nav').click(function() {
    $(".tab-pane").load($('#page-2')); 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: $('.ss-help .next-nav').click(function()
{
 
 $(".tab-pane").load($('#page-2'));
 return false;
 
  
});

Comment: where do the url's come from? This question could use some proper clarification on precise behavior and process flow expected

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see

```
$('.ss-help .next-nav').click(function() {
    $(".tab-pane").load($('#page-2')); 
    return false; 
});
```

should be

```
$('.tab-content').on('click', '.next-nav',function() {
    $(".tab-pane").load('some html or something'); 
    return false; 
});
```

Question limits the quality of this response here

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't see an AJAX in your post, I am assuming you just want to show/hide elements. In that case, I suggest running the following snippet for an example of cycling through multiple `tab-pane`'s using "Next" and "Previous" buttons.

(It can be tweaked to stop at the first or last `tab-pane`'s)

```js
$('.tab-content')
  .on('click', '.next', function (event) {
    var $curr = $('.tab-pane.active');
    var $next = $curr.next('.tab-pane');
    $curr.removeClass('active');
    if (!$next.length) {
      $next = $('.tab-pane:eq(0)'); // grab first tab-pane element
    }
    $next.addClass('active');
  })
  .on('click', '.previous', function (event) {
    var $curr = $('.tab-pane.active');
    var $prev = $curr.prev('.tab-pane');
    $curr.removeClass('active');
    console.log($prev);
    if (!$prev.length) {
      $prev = $('.tab-pane:last-child'); // grab last tab-pane element
    }
    $prev.addClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.tab-content .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content .tab-pane.active {
  display: block;
}

.next, .previous {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next:hover, .previous:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.tab-pane {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
  <span class="previous">Previous</span>
  <span class="next">Next</span>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="page-1">Page 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="page-2">Page 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="page-3">Page 3</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="page-4">Page 4</div>
</div>
```